# Aggregating Column Data into Descriptives

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table of data that looks like this. It basically contains a record for every person who arrived on a Sunday along with a few other descriptive variables.

```
Pt_ID  `Checkin_Date          ESI 1 or 2`     ESI 3    ESI4
  1     Sunday 07/Jan/2018        1           0        0
  2     Sunday 07/Jan/2018        1           0        0   
  3     Sunday 07/Jan/2018        0           1        0
  4     Sunday 14/Jan/2018        0           1        0
  5     Sunday 14/Jan/2018        0           1        0
  6     Sunday 14/Jan/2018        0           0        1
  7    Sunday 21/Jan/2018         1           0        0   
  8    Sunday 21/Jan/2018         1           0        0
```

I would like to calculate a variable that displays the count of the number of people who arrived on a given Sunday and the percentage of people who were "ESI 1 or 2"

I'd like the output to look like this...

```
  Checkin_Date        Count         ESI 1 or 2
Sunday 07/Jan/2018      3               66%
Sunday 14/Jan/2018      3                0%
Sunday 21/Jan/2018      2              100%
```

I have the following code that does the count but am struggling with creating the percentages.

```
Select checkin_date, count (pt_Id) as [Number of Patients Seen]
from [Fast Track Quality Research v1]
group by checkin_date
```

Comment: SQL Server or MS-Access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `ESI 1 or 2` field contains only 1s and 0s, `AVG` should yield the desired result, e.g.:

```sql
select checkin_date, count(pt_Id) as [Number of Patients Seen], avg([esi 1 or 2])*100 as pct
from [Fast Track Quality Research v1]
group by checkin_date
```

Alternatively `SUM/COUNT`  e.g.:

```sql
select checkin_date, count(pt_Id) as [Number of Patients Seen], 100*sum([esi 1 or 2])/count(pt_Id) as pct
from [Fast Track Quality Research v1]
group by checkin_date
```